# Transistor Selection on current source circuit?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, current-source, pnp

I am simulating a constant current source using PSpice

[image]

[image]

The only difference is the PNP transistor i used. and Their specification seems to be similar.

Below is the link for the two transistors.

[BC859B Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/BC859_BC860-840055.pdf)

[MMBT3906LT1G Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/MMBT3906LT1-D-112192.pdf)

What is the difference between the two transistors that makes one circuit work, and the other circuit don't?

Comment: -1 for incomprehensible schematics. If you had drawn your schematic more clearly you would have likely seen the obvious errors for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

THis is from the datasheet.  Your schematic needs signal names and you should check the connections.

[image]

With V+ = 5V and 2V across this R3 and same V on R1 the current is constant thru the collector when terminated.   The 2nd transistor is optional for ratio current amplification. (mirror)

I can explain further if needed.

Answer (score -2):

You've got over 5.38 volts across Emitter_Base in that first circuit.

The symbol is broken. Diodes don't need 5.38 volts to be forward-biased.

Comment: Going for short and sweet but failing to answer the question again